# Voltage ramp in INA125 output

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I am using a INA125P to amplify the signal from a beam load cell - and I have noticed a frequent ramp in my INA125P output signal, of about 100mV every 200uS.

EDIT: My gain is roughly 800x.

[image]

I have scoped various locations in the circuit, including the cell excitation, the cell output (unamplified) and the general circuit supply, and cannot see the same pattern anywhere - suggesting this is being introduced inside of the INA125P.
I have tested a few INA125P chips to rule out the damage - all are identical.

EDIT:
Here is the Circuit.io (excuse some of the nonsensical layout... circuits.io layout is an exercise in futility).
Note: I have added in the low pass filters... I haven't tried the actual circuit yet... this weekend most likely.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You don't say what your gain is. And your pulses are coming every 200 usec, not every 50.

Comment: A schematic would be helpful. Do you have decoupling capacitors on the supply lines? What does the output load look like?

Comment: sorry @SpehroPefhany no schematic right now - very soon though! No I don't have any decoupling caps.

Comment: Any capacitors at all?

Comment: Hahaha.... nooooo no capacitors... I totally thought there should be some in there somewhere - I'm very much learning as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb here, and suggest that you are seeing pickup of a 5 KHz source. I'm assuming you have a pretty high gain - load cells usually have an output of ~ 1 mV / V of excitation, which means you need gains of ~ 1000. Gains this high, combined with the very high input impedance (10^11 ohms) of the INA125, make for extreme susceptibility to pickup. This also would explain why you don't see these pulses elsewhere - at a gain of 1000, they are only 100 uV (riding on half the excitation level) at the source.

I assume you're using the standard circuit shown in the data sheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina125.pdf

Start by making sure that both the excitation +/- and the output +/- are at least twisted pair, and preferably shielded twisted pair. Second, put a 10 uF non-polarized capacitor across the inputs. Even better, instead of running the load cell directly into the INA125, add a pair of low-pass filters: 10 k to each input and a 1 uF capacitor to ground for each of the inputs. Do this right at the IC. If you put the input filters in, don't bother with the cap across the inputs.

This will, of course, cut the frequency response of the system somewhat. If you need millisecond response, you'll have to be more careful with your wiring.

Comment: Thanks - the RC addition perfectly smoothed the output. I added the RCs to each amp input, one at a time. Any idea why I got such a weird curve when I only had one RC applied? It was a charge/discharge type signal...